# Use of memory in PHP application (CakePHP). Or is it Linux configuration?

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, cakephp, memory

In last few days I have very big problem with memory on server where is hosted my web application. Memory usage goes up and up, and it never get released. After a few minutes of using CakePHP application, memory is 100% used, due to that server starts using swap file, and it makes server unusable.

I have 5159948k of memory, with swap file of 4128764k.

In php.ini, memory limit is set as:

memory_limit = 1024M

I have to say that there was no problem until 2-3 days ago. There where some simular problems in the past, but I solved it by recreating indexes in database, together with database defragmentation. Today I tried to do the same, but this time I did not solved the issue.

Where can be a problem? I'm not sure, but it looks like that swap gets just a bit less used if I turn MySQL off. Also, to mention that in database I don't have anything "heavy".

If you can help me with this issue please...

**UPDATE:** i found out that Apache is causing a problem, because when I turn it off, memory gets released.... can you help me what to do to solve this problem...

Comment: Well, I think it is tricky to suggest any solution here. But it doesn't seem that the problem might be with CakePHP or memory_limit. Are you using a dedicated or shared hosting? Does your application runs any crons or similar processes that run periodically? Perhaps, there might be an incorrectly written logic that never completes, like an unending loop?

Comment: Are you using a foreign Script built using CakePHP or is it your own application built using CakePHP? If it's a foreign script from a certain company I have in mind I know the issue...

Comment: no, it's mine application, written over a year ago

Comment: Since you're using CakePHP, there is a good chance your find queries are not contained correctly (a badly joined table without a foreign key will bring back an entire table as an associated model. Every time.)

Answer (score 1):

It would be absolutely crazy if your server needed 1024M as the memory_limit; because this limit is actually *per request*. This means if you have 8 concurrent users, you'll already need 8GB in a worst case scenario.

It's very important to figure out what it is that's actually consuming all this memory. Is it the webserver, a PHP process, a MySQL process? Based on that you can make the next steps to isolate what's doing this and how you can solve this.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure, but i think that is mysql. tell me please about that memory_limit... i set it up so big, because application "asked" more memory (now it's too late to change application). for sure some memory is "missing". also one more problem is that it was online without any problem until few days ago, and in that time there is no more users than before. also, can you tell me why amount of used memory stays on that high level, and why it does not goes down?

Comment: If your application requires that much memory, this is exactly what's broken. I'm telling you this is not normal for a PHP application. Any PHP app that can fill up that much will likely also take a while to do so, which is probably why it appears it never goes away. Try to find out why the application needs this much.

Comment: And you have to be 100% sure of what's eating the memory. Just run 'top' or ask your system administrator.

Comment: But why this memory never gets released? also, i found out that Apache is causing a problem, because when I turn it off, memory gets released....

Comment: Could just be some form of caching

Comment: Some form of caching of php application? Ok, i will try to turn off caching by Cake...

Comment: No, turning off CakePHP caching will probably not do anything. You'll really need to start profiling your application and the cause of the problem; don't try to fix symptoms

Answer (score 0):

> i found out that Apache is causing a problem, because when I turn it off, memory gets released

If you pull the power cable out that will reduce memory too. You've not provided any relevant information about what investigation you've done, how the services on your box are accessed nor the pattern of workload. But at a guess, most of the database workload will be driven by web requests - so switching off apache will cause mysql to release its memory.

What is your average response times for web requests? Are you using compression for PHP and static content? What is your average number of concurrent requests? Are you running a PHP accelerator? Have you tuned the caching of content?

A 1G memory limit is absurdly high - if your application needs this amount of memory then it needs to be refactored.

Comment: What is your average response times for web requests - in normal circumstances it was around 300ms, but this server is on really slow link. when i have this problem web application is unusable, it loads forever. yes, i use compression, and it's CakePHP application. tried to add 256mb for memory, but problem is still the same. Also I did tried to add new memory module and this morning also I moved hard drives to another PC box, but always same problem. Tonight I will reinstall Linux, to see what will happen...